# Linker issue when switch to Xcode7, Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: _objc_readClassPair

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

I got this error when I try to use the latest xcode, which is 7.1.1, but got 2 linker error:
[Error msg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEofp.png)

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_objc_readClassPair", referenced from:
      __ARCLite__load() in libarclite_iphoneos.a(arclite.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

don't know how to figure this out, anyone can help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You didn't bother searching the internet either did you?  [This](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17757) was the top hit when googling for `_objc_readClassPair`.

Comment: Thanks bro, by adding "-Xlinker -U -Xlinker _objc_readClassPair" to the "Other Linker Flags" fixed that issue.

Comment: David Kong: Can you make an answer from your comment, so that everyone could rate it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding "-Xlinker -U -Xlinker _objc_readClassPair" to the "Other Linker Flags" fixed that issue.